# ASP Core Routing POST page can't be found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the standard asp core routes setup:

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "areas",
    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
endpoints.MapRazorPages();
```

Then I have 4 actions (2 get and 2 post):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
{...}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, CustomDTO customDTO)
{...}

public async Task<IActionResult> Review(int? id)
{...}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Review(int id, DifferentCustomDTO differentCustomDTO)
{...}
```

The Review form razor starts like this:

```
<form asp-action="Review">
```

Both urls look like this:

```
https://localhost/MyController/Review/12
```

Under normal circumstances, the POST action would get its id from the url value and the CustomDTO from the form's submitted data. This was working until recently I started getting this:

```
This localhost page can’t be found No webpage was found for the web address: 
https://localhost/MyController/Review/12
HTTP ERROR 404
```

I tried removing 2 of the 4 to see if there was some kind of conflict, but that didn't change anything.
How can I find what I screwed up?

Comment: `This was working until recently I started getting this`have you made any changes, does it just not work for this controller action? Can you show us the whole form and the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add some data to the post body because if you are using this URL:

`https://localhost/MyController/Review/12`

Then the HTML Body of the post request will be empty. Try to add hidden field to the form like:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(e => e.Id)
```